# Comparing all combinations of lines within two columns using awk + if statement

Tags: awk, scripting

I have a file with 11 Columns of data deliminated by a space between each. For each line in column 2, I need to find the closest value in column 9. So below it would take the first entry in column 2 (0.01) and find the closest value in column 9 (0.009 in line 3).

File layout:

```
x 0.01 x x x x x x 0.002 x x
x 0.034 x x x x x x 0.0045 x x
x 0.002 x x x x x x 0.009 z z
x 0.002 x x x x x x 0.0021 x x
x 0.015 x x x x x x 0.0031 x x
```

Current code:

```
awk '{
if (sqrt(($2)^2-($9)^2)<0.0001)
   print "Particle ID  "$1" is within 2D of wall"
}' filename
```

Which I think has two problems:

1) This doesn't compare every permutation, just for each line in the columns

2) It only checks if they are within a certain range, not the closest.

Desired output would be a new file which is something like

```
x 0.01 x x x x x x 0.009 z z
```

and so on for all the other lines

Comment: can u provide a sample data?

Comment: I suspect it's going to be ugly in a general purpose language like Awk: have a look at [Populate numpy matrix from the difference of two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704565/populate-numpy-matrix-from-the-difference-of-two-vectors)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `awk` macro of [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr):

```
$ txr closest.tl < data
x 0.01 x x x x x x 0.009 x x
x 0.034 x x x x x x 0.009 x x
x 0.002 x x x x x x 0.0021 z z
x 0.002 x x x x x x 0.0021 x x
x 0.015 x x x x x x 0.009 x x
```

Code in `closest.tl`:

```
(build
  (awk
    ((fconv - r : : r - -) (add f))
    (:end (let ((fs (get)))
            (each ((f fs))
              (let ((min (find-min fs : (op abs (- [f 1] [@1 8])))))
                (set [f 8] [min 8])
                (prn . f)))))))
```

- `build` creates an environment for procedurally constructing an implicit list. Inside the code enclosed by `build`, we use `(add ...)` to add an item to the implicit list and `(get)` to retrieve the list.
- Inside the `build` environment, we have an instance of the `awk` macro. This macro has one condition-action rule and one `:end` rule. In the condition-action rule we have a `(fconv ...)` expression as the condition. This is unconditionally true, so we match each record. The `fconv` performs conversion of selected fields to floating point (`r` = "real"). The action just does `(add f)` which means: add the list of current fields to the implicit list. Thus we build up the data as a list of rows, which are lists of fields.

  > `fconv` is needed because TXR Lisp is a strongly typed language. The `awk` macro implements a lot of the semantics of Awk, but not the duck typing whereby we can treat a string like `"3.14"` as a number.
- When the data ends, the `:end` clause of `awk` fires, and that's where we do the closest distance processing. We get the rows into a variable called `fs`, and iterate a variable `f` for each row. For each row, we find the minimum item from `fs`, where the item is the absolute value of the difference between that row's field 1 and field 8 from each row being examined. When we find the minimum distance row, we replace this row's field 8 with that minimum distance row's field 8.

  > Note that the fields are numbered from 0: `[f 0]`, `[f 1]`, ... Unlike in Awk, there is no convention that the zero field is the whole record; the whole record is called `rec`.
- Having replaced field `[f 8]` with the minimum distance one, we print the fields.